# OpenTelemetry SqlClient instrumentation is not working

Tags: .net-core, open-telemetry

I'd like to use `OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient` to collect traces about database operations in ASP.NET Core Web Server. But when I run the code, no trace from `Instrumentation.SqlClient` is printed on console, only traces from `Instrumentation.AspNetCore` are shown.

My `Program.cs`:

```
using Dapper;
using MySqlConnector;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
{
    tracerProviderBuilder
        .AddConsoleExporter()
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddSqlClientInstrumentation();
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/get", async (string userName) =>
{
    using var conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password=password;port=3306;database=account;");
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    var userId = await conn.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<int>(
        "SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE UserName = @userName;",
        new {userName});
    return userId;
});

app.Run();
```

Console ouput when I connect to `localhost/get?userName=username`:

```
Activity.TraceId:          238ee4b50fa74a119a090d9397ba9e2f
Activity.SpanId:           b1e79de3c59d471a
Activity.TraceFlags:           Recorded
Activity.ActivitySourceName: OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore
Activity.DisplayName: /get
Activity.Kind:        Server
Activity.StartTime:   2022-06-27T06:49:53.6323013Z
Activity.Duration:    00:00:00.4652234
Activity.Tags:
    http.host: localhost:5265
    http.method: GET
    http.target: /get
    http.url: http://localhost:5265/get?userName=testuser0001
    http.user_agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    http.status_code: 200
   StatusCode : UNSET
Resource associated with Activity:
    service.name: unknown_service:WebApplication1
```

[Expected Output](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/semantic_conventions/database.md#mysql)

[About OpenTelemetry SqlClient Instrumentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AddSqlClientInstrumentation` is for instrumenting a "SQL Server" client. I.e. `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and `System.Data.SqlClient` ([source](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient/README.md)).

However, you use MySql (hence your use of `MySqlConnection` instead of `SqlConnection`).

You'll have to research if there is any .NET OpenTelemetry integration for MySql (clients) available.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.EntityFrameworkCore

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-contrib/tree/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.EntityFrameworkCore